# Calling Cocoa APIs from C

Tags: c, cocoa, macos

I don't know if this is possible, but having code in plain C, is it possible to call Cocoa API's from it?
Something like `#include <cocoa.h>`, add the corresponding library and go for it?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you link against the Cocoa or Foundation frameworks, you can use objective-c within your C code. However, if you want to use the normal messaging syntax, you will have to change the file extension from .c to .m so that it is compiled as objective-c. If you keep the .c extension, you will only be able to use the c-style runtime calls to interact with objective-objects (i.e. `objc_msgSend`, `objc_getClass`, etc.).

Examples: Within a .m file

```
void cFunction() {
    [[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

Within a .c file

```
void cFunction() {
    void* cls = objc_getClass("NSString");
    void* obj = objc_msgSend(cls, NSSelectorFromString(CFSTR("alloc")));
    obj = objc_msgSend(obj, NSSelectorFromString(CFSTR("init")));
}
```

If you choose the second method, see the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418).

Comment: In general, calling `objc_msgSend` as-is is the wrong thing. You should cast it to an appropriate function type: `typedef CFStringRef (*StringWithStringIMP)(id, SEL, CFStringRef); CFStringRef string = ((StringWithStringIMP)objc_msgSend)(objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_getUid("foo"), CFSTR("This is pointless."));`

Comment: Cool. How do I do this? How do I link against the Cocoa or Foundation framework? is it at project level? can I `#include` it? I would like to continue to have just plain C files and a Makefile to compile it and link it (not relying on XCode to do it)

Comment: @MrAleph You will need to tell GCC to link against the framework. Use `-Xlinker -framework -Xlinker Foundation` to do this. You should do `#include <Foundation/NSObjcRuntime.h>` to get the current runtime header.

Comment: @MrAleph: I strongly recommend against using `objc_msgSend` from `.c` file. Just use `.m`. You can compile an `.m` file without XCode, by using `gcc foo.m -o foo.o -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is a very thin wrapper on top of C. The compiler just translates

```
 [obj message:argument];
```

into a C-call

```
 obj_msgSend(obj,@selector(message:),argument);
```

and that's it (where `@selector(message:)` is a magic encoding turning a selector (method name) into a computer-understandable-thingy.)

As such, there is not much difference between Objective-C and C from the compiler's viewpoint. For example, you can compile a pure C program with an Objective-C compiler, with exactly the same result as you would get by compiling with a C compiler.

So, the easiest way to "mix" a bit of Objective-C with C is to use `.m` extension so that the compiler use Objective-C.

That doesn't make your program suddenly very Objective-C-y. You can keep your program almost pure C, with the extension `.m`. With `.m`, you can add a few lines of Objective-C message calls without problems.

Comment: Would I be able to write a simple Makefile to compile and link this?

Comment: It's really just source files with a different suffix and a different compiler call. The object files created are just plain object files like created by pure C compilers.