# How to create a D-Cocoa Port?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, d

I am planning to use D for creating native applications on Mac OS X. For that, of course, D must interact with the Cocoa API. I have no knowledge of how this bindings could be done. I've already looked at [Cocado](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cocodao/) and do know the Michel Fortin's [D-ObjC bridge](http://michelf.com/projects/d-objc/), and would like to be enlightened about some details:

- What is their (or any other possible) approach of porting Cocoa to D? — here I essentially ask for technical reading sources (books/articles/references, etc);
- Is it possible to establish an ABI compatibility with ObjC directly or through the C ABI? — There's a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901508/calling-cocoa-apis-from-c) where the answers describe what could be achieved with [Objective-C's Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html);
- Is it feasible to make this kind of stuff work nicely and get the level of performance and stability like, e.g., with Qt framework on Mac OS X?

I have no experience at all in this field so forgive me any technical faults. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- what most ports of Cocoa ports will do is translate the .h into .di and provide a thin wrapper and general utils,

  this will possibly include some syntactic sugar through the `opDispatch(string sel,A...)(A args)` overload that will translate `obj.call1(arg1).call2(arg2)` to the correct `obj_msgsend(obj.ptr,NSSelectorFromString(sel),args)` calls
- it is possible through the C ABI you can read more about that [in the D spec](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html)
- sure it's possible however many things that the Obj. C compiler can check the D compiler cannot check requiring unittests to find those

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's indeed the way the port should be implemented, but due to the problems described by Jacob Carlborg (see my own answer for this question), I will try to use a modified version of the D compiler to get the things work.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a more detailed answer to this question on the dlang.org [forum](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/jhijexinmerdaufnltwm@forum.dlang.org) from Jacob Carlborg.